# How do I add the permission "LOAD FROM INFILE" to my database?

Tags: mysql, database, permissions

Suppose I did this:

> CREATE DATABASE TEST;
>   GRANT ALL ON TEST.* TO "user"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "mypass";

How do I grant `load from infile` to "user"?

Comment: grant all includes "file" privilege :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
grant file on *.* to "user"@"%" identified by 'xxxx';
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file